# How to use an instance reference in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, winforms

I am working on a Winforms application written in C#, which is having trouble matching static items.

Here is my code

```
InitializeComponent();

string pnumber = Calculate.Peoplenumber.Text;
int peoplenumber = int.Parse(Calculate.Peoplenumber.Text);
int daynumber = int.Parse(Calculate.Daynumber.Text);
int Totalcost = int.Parse(Calculate.totalcost.Text);

int TripBasicCost = Totalcost / daynumber;
int TripDayCost = TripBasicCost / peoplenumber;
```

Referencing all of the `Calculate.FormName` objects produces this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.

On observing the link in form1.cs, where the object link occurs, here is the code for one connection:

```
 public void Peoplenumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 }
```

But changing this to public static void produces this error:

> 'Calculate.Peoplenumber_TextChanged(object, EventArgs)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

I am wondering how to appropriately use an instance reference here?

Comment: What *static items*? You're trying to get the text content of some TextBoxes. Where? In a Form other than the one that contains those Controls? What is `Calculate`? Is it the Form that you refer to as `form1`? -- What are `the link` and *the object link*? `Peoplenumber_TextChanged` is an event handler. -- If you need to pass some data from a Form to another, collect the data you need in a class object and pass this reference to  e.g., the Constuctor of the Form that needs it, from the Form that creates its Instance (as probably the most trivial example).

Comment: Calculate is the form I am using, yes. I am needing to pass the data from peoplenumber_textchanged as a static string, thank you.

Comment: We can't easily make sense of your question because it contains so many mistakes/misconceptions. Better to just tell us what you have and what you want to do . **For example**:  "I have two forms, CalculateForm and TotalForm. CalculateForm has a textbox Operator1TextBox. TotalForm shows CalculateForm and the user types a number into it then clicks OK which hides the form. The code in TotalForm then needs to retrieve the typed value and add it to the total. Here is the code I wrote so far" - if you stated your problem like that, we could do something with it

Comment: "But changing this to public static void produces this error" - it feels very unlikely that this *should be* static - in fact, the number of static items in this scenario should approach zero; but the only way for us to understand is to *see the code*

Answer (score 0):

why cant you create a model to collect your as mentioned in one of the comment.
inject the model in the constructor when calling form2 but calling this
Peoplenumber_TextChanged might not work well though.

```
     public class MyClass
    {
        public int Peoplenumber { get; set; }
        public int Daynumber { get; set; }
        public int totalcost { get; set; }
    }

    public Form2(MyClass model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int peoplenumber = model.Peoplenumber;
        int daynumber = model.Daynumber;
        int Totalcost = model.totalcost;
        int TripBasicCost = Totalcost / daynumber;
        int TripDayCost = TripBasicCost / peoplenumber;
    }

    public Calculate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //your other code

     //Form2 calling event
        var model = new MyClass
        {
            Peoplenumber = int.Parse(Peoplenumber.Text),
            Daynumber = int.Parse(Daynumber.Text),
            totalcost = int.Parse(totalcost.Text)
        };
            //you can validate values in the textboxes
        new Form2(model).ShowDialog();
       
    }
```

Comment: Will try it, thank you.